# Delete old rows not present in new feed

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I've a data feed that updates daily and I need to insert it into a table. I'd like to update rows with the same id but with different data, add non existent data and delete rows that don't exist anymore. I'm having problems with the last task, I can't seem to delete the rows from previous runs that don't exist in the new feed anymore.

This is what I have, the "listings" table with some test data:

```
INSERT INTO public.listings(
id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date)
VALUES 

(1, 100, '2021-05-03', 3, 'mf', '2021-01-01'),
(2, 200, '2021-05-03', 4, 'pmf', '2021-01-01'),
(3, 300, '2021-05-04', 5, 'jorge', '2021-01-01'),
(4, 400, '2021-05-05', 3, 'yuyu', '2021-01-01'),
(5, 500, '2021-05-06', 3, 'papo', '2021-01-01');
```

A new insert clause (update to the feed):

```
INSERT INTO listings AS p (id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date)
VALUES
  (1, 125, '2021-04-30', 4, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
, (2, 200, '2021-05-03', 4, 'pmf', '2021-01-01')
, (6, 250, '2021-04-30', 3, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
ON CONFLICT (id)  -- simple clause
DO UPDATE
SET    pub_date = EXCLUDED.pub_date
     , price     = EXCLUDED.price
     , rooms     = EXCLUDED.rooms
     , updated_date = EXCLUDED.updated_date
WHERE (p.pub_date, p.price, p.rooms, p.updated_date) IS DISTINCT FROM
      (EXCLUDED.pub_date, EXCLUDED.price, EXCLUDED.rooms, EXCLUDED.updated_date);
```

And this is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_prop_backup()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO old_listings 
   VALUES (OLD.*);
   
   DELETE FROM listings --this sentence generates an error on id duplicity
   WHERE listings.id = OLD.id;
   
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER prop_listings_upd_bef
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON listings
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_prop_backup();
```

This already works to update the existing rows and insert the new ones, but it doesn't work for the rows that are not existant anymore on the update feed. There's something I'm doing wrong (or not doing) but I can't seem to come up with the solution.

The "old_listings" table contains the rows that doesn't exist on the new feed, because the data is updated or deleted.

The result of running the two insert queries has to be (for the listings table):

```
  (1, 125, '2021-04-30', 4, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
, (2, 200, '2021-05-03', 4, 'pmf', '2021-01-01')
, (6, 250, '2021-04-30', 3, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
```

And the old_listings table:

```
(1, 100, '2021-05-03', 3, 'mf', '2021-01-01'),
(3, 300, '2021-05-04', 5, 'jorge', '2021-01-01'),
(4, 400, '2021-05-05', 3, 'yuyu', '2021-01-01'),
(5, 500, '2021-05-06', 3, 'papo', '2021-01-01');
```

Comment: First, could you please show the trigger associated to the function `trg_prop_backup()` : `CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_prop_backup()` ? Then, I'm confused about the deletion of the rows with id = 3, 4, 5 from table `listings` and the insert of the corresponding rows in the table `old_listings`, both actions trigerred by the insert/update of the rows with id = 1, 2, 6 in the table `listings` ? I don't see how to make it happen ?

Comment: I would suggest instead to first delete all the rows from the table `listings` and insert them in the table `old_listings`, and then to delete from the table `old_listings` all the rows which correspond to the rows updated in the table `listings`. In this way, you should get the expected result.

Comment: Yes, there was some code missing in the trigger section. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

- Add an extra timestamp field `series_ts` in table `listings` and set its value to `current_timestamp` upon insert or update;
- remove the `where` clause of your `insert on conflict update` query so that `series_ts` will be updated even for equivalent records;
- delete all `listings` records whose `series_ts` is not equal to `current_timestamp` in the same transaction with the insert query.

In order to do this first create a 'before insert or update for each row' trigger that executes this function:

```sql
create function set_listings_series_ts() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
 new.series_ts := current_timestamp;
 return new;
end; $$;
```

After you have this in place run:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO listings AS p (id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date)
VALUES
  (1, 125, '2021-04-30', 4, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
, (2, 200, '2021-05-03', 4, 'pmf', '2021-01-01')
, (6, 250, '2021-04-30', 3, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
ON CONFLICT (id)  -- simple clause
DO UPDATE
SET    pub_date = EXCLUDED.pub_date
     , price     = EXCLUDED.price
     , rooms     = EXCLUDED.rooms
     , updated_date = EXCLUDED.updated_date; -- your query w/o WHERE

WITH t as 
(
  delete from listings 
  where series_ts < current_timestamp 
  returning *
)
insert into old_listings select * from t; -- delete old data, save in old_listings

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You may do this w/o a trigger too if you change the 'insert ... update' query.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion :

First delete all the rows in the table `listings`, and create the corresponding rows in the table `old_listings` :

```
WITH list AS
(  DELETE FROM listings
    WHERE true
  RETURNING id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date
)
INSERT INTO old_listings (id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date)
SELECT id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date
FROM list ;
```

Then insert the new rows in table `listings` and delete the corresponding rows in the table `old_listing` by trigger :

```
INSERT INTO listings AS p (id, price, pub_date, rooms, publisher, updated_date)
VALUES
  (1, 125, '2021-04-30', 4, 'mf', '2021-10-30')
, (2, 200, '2021-05-03', 4, 'pmf', '2021-01-01')
, (6, 250, '2021-04-30', 3, 'mf', '2021-10-30')

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_del_bacckup()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM old_listings
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_del_bacckup
AFTER INSERT ON listings
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_del_bacckup();
```

PS : you also have to manage the conflicts in the table `old_listings` when successive feed try to insert rows with ids which already exist